# Show that a complex sum is locally but not uniformly convergent

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have shown that the $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{3^n+z^n}$ converges locally uniformly on $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z|<3\}$ but I am struggling to show that it is not uniformly convergent on this region. I suspect that problems arise around $z=-3$ but since $-3$ isn't included in the region $D$ I don't know how to go about this.

The only test I am aware of (to show $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$) is showing that there is some sequence $x_n\in D$ such that $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\geq c$ for some constant $c>0$. I have tried doing a similar thing here with the sum, assuming that it converges to some limit function $F$ but it doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: It's not only around $-3$ that problems arise, also around $\pm 3i$ (since $z^n$ is very close to $- 3^n$ for $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ if $z$ is close to $\pm 3 i$), generally around $3\cdot \omega$ for all $\omega$ such that $\omega^k = -1$ for some $k$. These points are dense on the circle $\lvert z\rvert = 3$. Note that the terms of a uniformly convergent series must eventually be bounded.

Comment: Intuitively this makes sense but I am still unsure how to prove it. What point do I pick so that I can show the terms are eventually unbounded? I have tried with $z=-3 + \epsilon$ and splitting the sum into even and odd terms but my argument is pretty hand-wavey from then on

Comment: If we have uniform convergence, there is an $N$ such that $$\biggl\lvert f(x) - \sum_{k = 0}^n f_k(x) \biggr\rvert \leqslant 1$$ for all $n \geqslant N$. Consider the difference between two consecutive partial sums of the series. That is $f_n(x)$. For $n > N$, it follows from the above that $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leqslant 2$ for all $x$. Now looking at $f_n(-3+\epsilon)$ for odd $n$ and letting $\epsilon \to 0$ shows that the odd-indexed terms aren't bounded.

Comment: I assume that by the difference between 2 'consecutive partial sums' you mean $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nf_k(x) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f_k(x)$ right? And how does it follow that $|f_n(x)|\leq 2$?

Comment: Correct. It follows from the triangle inequality, $\lvert a - c\rvert \leqslant \lvert a - b\rvert + \lvert b - c\rvert$. Here $b$ is the limit function, $a$ and $c$ the partial sums.